# php - for loop for each month of year

Tags: php, date, loops, for-loop

I want a loop that checks the current month, 12 months in the future and 4 months in the past.

For example: Today is 1st August 08. My loop should go through April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, and August.

I have tried strotime but I don't know how I can loop 4 months back and 12 months in the future.

Here is my code

```
$i = 1; 
$month = strtotime('2013-08-01');

    while($i <= 12) {
        $month_name = date('F', $month);
        echo $month_name;
        echo "<br>";

        $month = strtotime('+1 month', $month);
        $i++;
```

Comment: start with the timestamp four months ago, and expand your loop to 16 months would be an easy way to go

Answer (score 3):

I think Yoshi was almost there with [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18122740/212940), but using [DatePeriod](http://php.net/dateperiod) with [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) is more consistent and makes for more readable code IMHO:-

```
$oneMonth = new \DateInterval('P1M');
$startDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d H:i:s', '1 00:00:00')->sub(new \DateInterval('P4M'));
$period = new \DatePeriod($startDate, $oneMonth, 16);

foreach($period as $date){
    //$date is an instance of \DateTime. I'm just var_dumping it for illustration
    var_dump($date);
}
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/vECYg)

Comment: +1 nice one, though personally I would remove some of the *one-time-use* variables.

Answer (score 2):

This can be quite tricky, here's how I would do it:

```
$month = date("n", "2013-08-01") - 1; // -1 to get 0-11 so we can do modulo

// since you want to go back 4 you can't just do $month - 4, use module trick:
$start_month = $month + 8 % 12;
// +8 % 12 is the same is -4 but without negative value issues
// 2 gives you: 2+8%12 = 10 and not -2

for ($i = 0; $i < 16; $i += 1) {
    $cur_month = ($start_month + $i) % 12 + 1; // +1 to get 1-12 range back
    $month_name = date('F Y', strtotime($cur_month . " months"));
    var_dump(month_name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?:

```
$start = -4;
$end = 12;

for($i=$start; $i<=$end;$i++) {
    $month_name = date('F Y', strtotime("$i months"));
    echo $month_name;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution:

```
for($i=-4; $i<=12; $i++) {
    echo date("F",strtotime( ($i > 0) ? "+$i months" : "$i months") )."\n";
}
```

Explanation:

The loop starts at -4 and goes all the way upto 12 (total 17, including 0). The ternary statement inside `strtotime()` simply checks if $i is positive, and if it is, a `+` is inserted so that we'll get the results for `strtotime("+1 months")` and similar.

**[Ta-da!](http://codepad.org/3HJmjAu7)**

Comment: How can this be modified to loop through January to December?

Comment: @Xitish You can adjust the loop variables. If you want readable code, you can also create a months list and store the month names there. If you want to do it in code, you could also do something like this: `$months = array_map(function ($i) { return date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1)); }, range(1, 12));`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, just slightly modified.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$i = 1;
$month = strtotime('-4 month');

while($i <= 16) {
    $month_name = date('F', $month);
    echo $month_name;
    echo "<br>";

    $month = strtotime('+1 month', $month);
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) is the easiest and more readable way. 
I would do it like this:

```
$from = new DateTime('-4 month');
$to   = new DateTime('+12 month');
while($from < $to){
  echo $from->modify('+1 month')->format('F');
}
```