# PHP Date ranges without the year. How to handle December/January loop-back

Tags: php

I have user defined date ranges. A date range might be from November 8 - March 26 for example. I need to determine if a given date (without the year) is between one of these ranges. I don't want to include the year because the user defined date ranges are recursive for each year.

My problems is that I don't know how to handle the loop-back between December 31 and Jan 1. I'm guessing that a PHP DatePeriod object would be the way to go but how can I exclude the year from it? If I have a date range from December 10 to February 15 how can I determine if Jan 11 is in that range without specifying the year?

Comment: good questions have code, it really helps us help you

Comment: Is "November 8 - March 26" an example of the user-defined format?

Comment: set the year to constant "eg 2015" so whatever the user input will be replaced by this year

Comment: The date ranges are stores in MySQL as "date" format. I do not have any code for this right now because I'm still trying to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: I was looking at this post... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122476/php-for-loop-for-each-month-of-year

 and it seems like DatePeriod is the way to go but it needs a year I think.

Comment: Just to be clear. If I have a user defined date range of December-10 to Feb-15. Jan-11 should return true becuase it is inside of the date range. The problem comes from the loop-back between December and January

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out if date is between two dates, ignoring year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540268/find-out-if-date-is-between-two-dates-ignoring-year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really not dealing with years, then making one up (as per [binnyb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32149129/628267)) is the way to go. The trick is adding the logic to test if the start date is after the end date - indicating that they are from different years.

An example solution (based on the answer to a similar question with years):

```
// For convenience, build MM-DD strings
$date1 = "11-8";
$date2 = "03-26";
$test = "01-15";

if (check_in_range($date1, $date2, $test)) echo "in range!";

function check_in_range($start_date, $end_date, $test_date)
{
    $year = '2000';

    $start_ts = strtotime($year.'-'.$start_date);
    $end_ts = strtotime($year.'-'.$end_date);
    $test_ts = strtotime($year.'-'.$test_date);

    if ($start_ts > $end_ts) {
      $year -= 1;
      $start_ts = strtotime($year.'-'.$start_date);
    }

    return (($test_ts >= $start_ts) && ($test_ts <= $end_ts));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is correct. That is exactly what needs to be done and I think it is more elegant than the other thread by decrementing the year.. I am marking this as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since the year doesn't matter, use one year and always that year when comparing dates.  Doing this allows you to create a valid `DateTime` object to use when checking if the test date is in range:

```
$constYear = '2000';
$dateStart = new DateTime($constYear . '-12-10');//December 10
$dateEnd = new DateTime($constYear . '-02-15');//February 15
$dateTest = new DateTime($constYear . '-01-11');//January 11
$isDateTestInRange = false;

if($dateTest > $dateStart && $dateTest < $dateEnd) {
  $isDateTestInRange = true;
}
```

Just be sure to not consider the year when using these variables (`$dateStart, $dateEnd, $dateText`) since it will include this constant `$constYear`(which is only used to create a valid date).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but when I do it this way it says that Jan 11 is not in range of the start and end dates. If I use the same year for everything and specify a date between December and January it will not work.

Comment: The problem is that if I specify a date range from December-1 to February-1 then ask if the date Jan-15 is in that range it will say no but it should say yes.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching I found a thread with the solution... For anyone interested this is it...

[Find out if date is between two dates, ignoring year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540268/find-out-if-date-is-between-two-dates-ignoring-year)